# Button not showing up

Tags: jquery, xhtml

Do you know why the button in the document doesn't reappear in Firefox 12 after the dialog box is closed?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="jqueryui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />    

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

        <style></style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#click").click(function() {
                    $("#dialog").attr("title", "save").text("This is the dialog box!").dialog({
                        buttons: {
                            "OK": function() {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
            <input type="button" value="click" id="click" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it disappear? There is nothing in your code example to say it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jyy96/6/

Your button reside inside `dialog` input hence it get lost.

move inout submit outside the dialog `div`

**Jouery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#click").click(function() {
        $("#dialog").attr("title", "save").text("This is the dialog box!").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

**html**

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="click" id="click" />
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Missed that, nice catch blud ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

You have the **button inside the dialog**, after the dialog gets closed, **it gets** inline `CSS` given by the `dialog()`:

```
display: none;
...
```

If you need the button always present, it should be outside the dialog content.

**EXAMPLE HTML**

```
<body> 
    <input type="button" value="click" id="click" /> 
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div> 
</body>
```